# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError when feeding numpy ndarray to placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, types, feed, placeholder

I want to run a simple neural network of 3 input "neurons" (with three features: height, weight, body fat) and 2 output "neurons" to classify new data, via softmax logistic regression, into either male or female). I made up this data just to practice data input to the model. Just like in the MNIST tutorial on the tensorflow website, but much simpler and tangible (instead of 784 input features -all the pixels of a given MNIST image- I only have 3, and instead of several batches to train our model I just want to train it several times in the same data).

I am aware this could be done via simpler algorithms, like k-means clustering. But I just want to learn how to input data when it is small.

I get this:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value lue for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype float

I don't know why... because I have converted the list values into np.float32 (which is the same as tf.float32) and I check it right before defining the function. Yet, I still get this annoying error. No matter what I change, I always get this error when loading into the first palceholder: X.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

    #TRAINING DATA  


        #3 VIs en columna

                    #est, pes, %gb_fat
persones = np.asarray([[175,70,2],   #H
                       [155,45,15],  #F 
                       [190,85,8],   #H
                       [185,90,7],   #H
                       [169,60,3],   #H
                       [150,40,13],  #F
                       [173,69,12]], dtype = np.float32)  #H

                        # H , D --> one-hot!! 
etiquetes = np.asarray([[1,0],
                        [0,1],
                        [1,0],
                        [1,0],
                        [1,0],
                        [0,1],
                        [1,0]], dtype = np.float32)


#TESTING DATA
persones_evaluacio = np.asarray([[190,89,4], #H
                                [155,52,16], #D
                                [171,55,18]], dtype = np.float32) #D

etiquetes_evaluacio = np.asarray([[1,0],
                                  [0,1],
                                  [0,1]], dtype = np.float32)

#WE TEST THE DATATYPES
print("dades dels nombres:   ",type(persones[0][0]))
print("tipus estructura de dades de la matriu:    ", type(persones))
time.sleep(3)
print("files de la matriu:")
time.sleep(0.5)
for i in range(len(persones)):
    print(persones[i])
time.sleep(0.5)


def classifica_H_D(nombre_VIs, categories_VD):

    #placeholders
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,nombre_VIs])
    y_reals = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,categories_VD])

    #variables
    w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nombre_VIs, categories_VD], dtype = tf.float32))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([categories_VD], dtype = tf.float32))


    #DEFINE MODEL
    y_predits = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,w) + b)

    # define LOSS FUNCTION
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_reals, logits=y_predits))

    #define optimizer to get cross_entropy minimized
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        print("finsaqui")
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(1000): #iterate over same data.
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x : persones, y_reals : etiquetes})
            if i%50:
                print(w.eval(), sess.run(cross_entropy))

        prediccio_correcta = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_predit,1), tf.argmax(y_correctes,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(prediccio_correcta, tf.float32))
        return "\naccuracy: {:.2f}".format(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: persones_evaluacio, y_reals: etiquetes_evaluacio}))


print(classifica_H_D(3,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this line:

```
 print(w.eval(), sess.run(cross_entropy)),
```

you need to feed input to it in the form below:

```
 print(w.eval(), sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict = {x : persones, y_reals : etiquetes}))
```

or a better way is:

```
 for i in range(1000): #iterate over same data.
     _, c_entropy = sess.run([train_step,cross_entropy], feed_dict = {x : persones, y_reals : etiquetes})
     if i%50:
        print(w.eval(), c_entropy)
```